# Using absolute URLs in Pelican static site generator ATOM feeds

Tags: python, rss, pelican

In the ATOM feeds (RSS) for my site created with Pelican, the URLs and images with a relative path point to http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogname/whatever instead of my site's path.

I have the SITEURL and Relative_URLS = False settings in Pelican. What else can I do to get the feeds to use absolute instead of relative paths?

I know there is an xml:base setting, but I don't know how to get Pelican to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, googling around, it seems like there's no way to do this. I'm going to have to resort to rewriting all the feed content by hacking the feed writer with absolute image paths and link URLs.